# AngularJS - inject variable in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

It seems to be a simple question but after a few month working with angular I'm still looking for a clean way to do it.

My template myTimePicker.html is defined in a directive so I got

```
<myTimePicker></myTimePicker>
```

Inside my template I have a "pickedTime" object

I need to pickup 3 different times and I dont' want to write 3 templates for the same code (obviously..). I would like to have it defined like a variable for a function, something like:

```
<myTimePicker ng-***="pickedTime1 as pickedTime" ></myTimePicker>
<myTimePicker ng-***="pickedTime2 as pickedTime" ></myTimePicker>
<myTimePicker ng-***="pickedTime3 as pickedTime" ></myTimePicker>
```

This works perfectly in ng-repeat when you write

```
ng-repeat="item in items"
```

You can use the same template for different items but each item has different variable values inside.

ng-init is not the solution because in this case:

```
<myTimePicker ng-init="pickedTime = pickedTime1"></myTimePicker>
<myTimePicker ng-init="pickedTime = pickedTime2"></myTimePicker>
...
```

pickedTime = pickedTime1 = pickedTime2 and they got all the same value pickedTime2

I hope it's clear, thank you for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom attribute and use it combined with an isolate scope:

```
<myTimePicker pickedTime="pickedTime1"></myTimePicker>
<myTimePicker pickedTime="pickedTime2"></myTimePicker>
<myTimePicker pickedTime="pickedTime3"></myTimePicker>

scope: {
    pickedTime: '='
}
```

This way you'd be able to inject the controller scope variables into the directive using the `pickedTime` attribute.

---

Here's a simple example using strings instead of real times:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.pickedTime1 = 'First time';
      $scope.pickedTime2 = 'Second time';
      $scope.pickedTime3 = 'Third time';
    }
  ])
  .directive('myTimePicker', function() {
    return {
      template: '<p>{{pickedTime}}</p>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        pickedTime: '='
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <my-time-picker picked-time="pickedTime1">1</my-time-picker>
  <my-time-picker picked-time="pickedTime2">2</my-time-picker>
  <my-time-picker picked-time="pickedTime3">3</my-time-picker>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<myTimePicker ng-init="pickedTime = pickedTime1"></myTimePicker>
<myTimePicker ng-init="pickedTime = pickedTime2"></myTimePicker>
...
```

ng-init doesn't work in above code is because model `pickedTime` is modified twice and set as `pickedTime2` at last.

If you use `<myTimePicker ng-repeat="pickedTime in pickedTimes" ></myTimePicker>`, for each `myTimePicker` element, `ng-repeat` will create an isolated scope and bind a new `pickedTime` to it, which can be accessed in your direcitve.